# Power Automate get current url

Tags: power-automate

Im using power apps and power automate. Power apps has a dropdown and a submit button. When the user submits the form the user is redirected into a new url with the dropdown value in the url. I want to get the current url in my power automate flow and eventually read the url param value.

Here is the url:https://myformpath.example&serverName=Chelones

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this a Canvas, Model Driven, or Power Page?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your Power Automate flow from app and pass values as parameter.

```
'YourFlowName'.Run(Argument1, Argument2, ...)
```

In Power Automate, add input parameters in Trigger.